# Removing the charge from charged object

Tags: electric-fields, charge

let's say I have an object with an electric charge Q. I'm not sure if I can remove charge 2Q from it so it will become negative (-Q) or I can't do it. To be specific I have this example: There are two objects, one with electric charge Q, another one uncharged. I remove charge q from charged object and give it to the uncharged one. In which case will be the force between them greatest: Q/2 or 2Q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move q/2, both end up with charge q/2 and the force will scale with $\frac{q^2}{4}$. If you move 2Q, the product of the charges will be $-2Q^2$ the magnitude of which is obviously bigger (although in the first place the force will be repulsive and in the second case it will be attractive).

Answer (score 0):

Suposse that -Q=ne, where e is the electron charge and n a natural number.
So, you can "add" positive charge to an object removing n electrons. 
Now imagine you have a object with charge 2Q, if you add 3n electrons, the final charge would be -2ne+3n3=(-2+3)ne=ne=-Q.
Remember that electrons has negative charge.